# how to set the frame of a UIView at runtime using lldb expr (DEBUGGING Console)

Tags: ios, xcode, console, lldb

I'm trying the following

```
(lldb) expr [_tvFeed setFrame:(CGRect)CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300)];
```

I'm getting

```
error: call to 'CGRectMake' is ambiguous
note: candidate function
note: candidate function
error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

I'm using XCode 6.1 , LLDB version lldb-320.4.152

Answer (score 5):

OK so here's a way that worked

```
expr CGRect rect; rect.origin.x=0; rect.origin.y=0; rect.size.width=320; rect.size.height=300; (void)[_tvFeed setFrame:rect];
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [C compound literals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html) to create CGRect, cause it is just a C struct

It will look like this

```
(lldb) expr [_tvFeed setFrame:(CGRect){0, 0, 320, 300}];
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
(lldb) e (void)[(id)0x7fe38ce039c0 setFrame:(CGRect){0,0,200,300}]
(lldb) caflush
```

Where `0x7fe38ce039c0` is the id of the view I want printed out by `pviews`. You need [chisel](https://github.com/facebook/chisel) for `pviews` and `caflush` to work in lldb.

```
(lldb) pviews
```

```
UIWindow: *0x7fe38ce1e330*; frame = (0 0; 414 896); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x6000006b57a0>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x6000008de480>>
   | <UILayoutContainerView: 0x7fe38ce2ab70; frame = (0 0; 414 896); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000008c2300>>
   |    | <UITransitionView: 0x7fe38cf079d0; frame = (0 0; 414 896); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000086d860>>
   |    |    | <UIViewControllerWrapperView: 0x7fe38cd22f40; frame = (0 0; 414 896); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000089a640>>
   |    |    |    | <UILayoutContainerView: 0x7fe38f6059c0; frame = (0 0; 414 896); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x60000068f450>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000890180>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UINavigationTransitionView: 0x7fe38f608170; frame = (0 0; 414 896); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000890700>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UIViewControllerWrapperView: 0x7fe38cf13280; frame = (0 0; 414 896); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000008de9a0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x7fe38f304940; frame = (0 0; 414 896); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000008c6800>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UINavigationBar: 0x7fe38f605bc0;
```